# Request does not work when app was in background for a few hours

Tags: android

When my application was in the background for a few hours and will be opened via history again, then the request does not go through (There is no log on the server neither, so it did not went through to the server) and an error occures (probably TIMEOUT), does anyone know what might cause this? The request is triggered when the application is in the foreground again, not in the background.

The request is triggered in another Fragment, and all data is shown correctly, but when the Button, which triggers the Request is clicked, the request does not go through, and there is no log on the server neither, but when the button is clicked AGAIN, the request DOES WORK and go through. The button is clicked immediately again after the time out error is shown.

My application was tested on a Pixel, I do not have access to the log of this phone unfortunately.

This behavior does not occure on my OnePlus Testing device.

Is there a possibility, that the device has internet connection, but the application has no internet access?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please add more details like code snippets, log etc. That'll help you get help quicker.

Comment: There are many probable causes. Please share here your code including the part where you send the request and how you handle background tasks.

Comment: Are you sure button clicking is handled properly? Try to add logcat to that place to double check

Answer (score 0):

System can freeze background work and networking when app is in background or device is in Doze mode to save device battery.

You have to use [WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/basics) to wake up your app in time you need or with some repetition and do all heavy work

Comment: Is this also the case, when the app is already in the foreground and the request gets triggered by the user? (Sorry, I just added more information)